# how to write a script for running a stat command for a directories and sub directories and print only most recent file

Tags: bash, timestamps

how to find most recent files in a directory? my script is giving some extra outputs with most recent file in the directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Please type in the directory you want all the files to be listed"
read directory
for entry in "$directory"/*
do
 (stat -c %y  "$directory"/* | tail -n 1)
done
 for D in "$entry"
 do
 (ls -ltr "$D" | tail -n 1)
done
```

current output :

```
2018-02-19 12:24:19.842748830 -0500
2018-02-19 12:24:19.842748830 -0500
2018-02-19 12:24:19.842748830 -0500
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Feb 19 12:19 test3.xml
```

my directory structure is as below

```
$ pwd
/nfs/test_library/myfolder/test

$ ls -ltr test
1.0  2.0  3.0

$ ls -ltr 1.0
test1.xml
$ ls -ltr 2.0
test2.xml
$ ls -ltr 3.0
test3.xml(which is the most recent file)
```

so I have to get the script working for printing only `test3.xml`

Comment: I think your second `for` loop is supposed to be nested in the first?  the variable `entry` doesn't exist outside of it.  However either way it wouldn't make sense because entry is going to be a single file so what should `D` be?

Comment: I think your `ls` may be broken if that is what the output of `ls -ltr` looks like on your system.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to accomplish what I believe you want with the following:

**GNU `stat`**

```
read -rp "Please type in the directory you want all the files to be listed" directory
if [ -d "$directory" ]; then
    find "$directory" -type f -exec stat --printf='%Y\t%n\n' {} \; | sort -n -k1,1 | tail -1
else
    echo "Error, please only specify a directory"
fi
```

**BSD `stat`**

```
read -rp "Please type in the directory you want all the files to be listed" directory
if [ -d "$directory" ]; then
    find "$directory" -type f -exec stat -F -t '%s' {} \; | sort -n -k6,6 | tail -1
else
    echo "Error, please only specify a directory"
fi
```

This will find all files in the specified directory recursively.  Then it will stat them with their modify timestamp in a UNIX EPOCH timestamp format.  Then it sorts them based on this timestamp field.  Finally it prints only the last result (most recently updated file).

Comment: please let me know how I can use this in the script

Comment: @user2576747: I have updated my answer to prompt for the directory to be searched.

Comment: getting below errorstat: invalid option -- 'F'
Try 'stat --help' for more information

Comment: @user2576747: I have modified my answer to include a solution using GNU `stat` which you are likely using.

Comment: my next task is to parse a xml file as an argument and output max size and cach size. here is the sample xml file.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-service>




   <service_info name="dummyapp" version="5.0"/>




   <object name="WebApplications">




      <item Location="dummyapp/ear/dummyapp.ear" name="dummy"/>




   </object>




   <object name="jdbc_oracle_nonxa">




      <item db_name="MYDB1" db_user="dummyapp_user" global_trans="None" initial_size="10" jndi_name="dummyapp-aty-ds" max_size="25" name="dummyapp-aty-ds" statement_cache_size="10"/>




   </object>

Comment: @user2576747:  Please ask any new questions as a new question.  You might want to look into some premade xml parsing tools first though.